# Obfuscate html content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a web widget, so I need to protect some sources for image and audio tags. Also I am putting the html content through a jquery function. Is there any javascript/jquery methods to obfuscate an entire div dynamically ? Following is my code :

```
function getHTML(){
    var html = '<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">' +
                    '<div style="margin-right: 16px;">' +
                        '<audio id="audio_widget" src="mysource/data1.mp3"></audio>' +
                        '<audio class="alternate_audio" src="mysource/data2.mp3"></audio>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>'+
        '<ul id="albumList" class="image-list">'+
            '<li><img src="mysource/image1.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100"></li>'+
            '<li><img src="mysource/image2.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100"></li>'+
        '</ul>';


//Through this function I want to obfuscate entire 'html' content.
var encoded = someFunction(html);  

return encoded;

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information about what it is you are trying to accomplish? Why do you want to encrypt the URL, and how are you passing this to a web browser?

Comment: I need to show my <img> and <audio> tag's src attributes displays the source url in any javascript-encoded format. To be straight, I want to hide all those sources from client side.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the url to your audio and image assets used in your webpage from the client? A web browser has to know where to grab these assets from, and needs a valid url. There are some other techniques you can use to obscure, encrypt, or hide the path to assets sitting on your server, but it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Why do you want to hide/encrypt these urls?

Comment: Yeah, but there are methods for encoding in Base62 or Base64 format. And I need an option to do it dynamically.

Comment: Why? It's useless, you can get any of these URLs for example in FF using Network console (even without FireBug), copy it with right-click menu command, show it in Page statistics, crypted or not...

Comment: Yes that's true. At some point we need to give actual URLs to the client side(browser) source fields for fetching the file.